# How to exclude some particular objects in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

I have Two tables in my Laravel application. 1 is collection and second one is q_collections. Collection table contains some objects. q_collections has many to one field to collections , means q_collections table has id of collection objects as c_id.I want to exclude the objects from collection table which are related with q_collections. There is a field `sd_item_id` which is common in both the tables. I want to filter the tables using this `sd_item_id` to get unique records or those records which are not available in q_collections.

Tables are like

```
//Collection
class CreateCollection extends Migration {
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('collection', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('collection');

}
}
//q_collections
class CreateQCollections extends Migration {
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('q_collections', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('sd_item_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('qc_id')->unsigned();     // question collection id 
            $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('qc_id')->references('id')->on('collection');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('q_collection');
}
}
```

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more? I'm not clear of what you want.

Comment: A table has OneToMany relationship with with table B. I want to fetch those items which are in table A but are not related with Table B. e.g I have two tables Question and Answers having one to many relationship. Question table has 10 questions but only 5 question's answers in Answers table. I want to fetch those 5 questions whose answers are not in Answers table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Laravel Query builder for this.

```
$collection_count=DB::table('q_collections')->where('sd_item_id','=',$item_id)->count();  
if($collection_count){  
    $sc=DB::table('q_collections')->where('sd_item_id','=',$item_id)->lists('qc_id');
}
else{
    $sc=array(0);
}
$collections=DB::table('collection')->whereNotIn('id',$sc)->get();
return Response::json($collections);
```

There may be some other ways to perform this task.
I am also new to laravel so I also say that this code is perfect or not but it will surely work.